# Allow anonymous users to post comments in sharepoint blog site

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am having blog site in sharepoint 2013. I've make the entire site anonymous. 
The anonymous users are able to view the posts but if I try to comment on post as anonymous user, it shows error that Access is denied. You do not have permission to access this resource or perform this operation.
What else I am required to do?Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance!